# Process Builder not firing when Approval Process updates field

Tags: process-builder, approval-process

I have a process builder that fires when the Opportunity Stage is set to Closed Won by the user. Works great....however, if I have my Approval Process update the Stage to Closed Won, the process builder does not fire off. Is this an order of execution issue? What could be wrong? Is there a workaround?

Comment: UPDATE: I did check 'Re-evaluate Workflow Rules After Field Change' and it seems to cause it to fire more than once.

Comment: Only way to trigger process builder after approval process change "Re-evaluate " checkbox. Only triggers get fired by default.
Did you check if your workflows or PB are somehow configured to create a loop ?